# Adding username in database after login

Tags: php

The thing is that i have a registrational and login form, after register I put the user data in a databse table. But now I am trying on login to put the login name into another table called `activeusers` so that i can use this table to show the active users.In this table there is `id` and `username`. But may be I'm doing mistake in the code somewhere so i will just show you what i mean:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$pass = md5($pass);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `userinfo` WHERE `uname` = '$uname' AND `pass` =    
'$pass'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `activeusers` WHERE `id` = NULL AND `username` =  
'$uname'");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `activeusers` (`id`, `username`,) VALUES (NULL, '$uname')") or  
die(mysql_error());
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
    if (isset($_SESSION['uname'])) {

     header('Location: main.php');
}

} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Wrong username or password"); 
</script>';
}
}
$form = <<<EOT
<div id="login">
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" required="required"/><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" required="required"/><br /><hr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" /><hr>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Close" onClick="hideElement('mydiv')"/>
</form>
</div>
EOT;

echo $form;     
?>
```

Comment: You have an extra comma after `username` in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Can you not just set a flag at login in the same table??

Comment: The little things are most difficult to see thank you very much!

Comment: I was stuck in it for an hour may be you helped me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another table is unnecessary. Just create bool type col in user table and updating it is better solution.

You can update every time when user refresh page.